# Python outputs only after script has finished in Komodo Edit

Tags: python, variables, output, temporary, komodoedit

Forgive me if it's a silly question. I'm new to Python and scripting languages. Now I'm using Komodo Edit to code and run Python programs. Each time I run it, I have to wait until the program finished execution to see my "print" results in the middle. I'm wondering if it's possible to see realtime outputs as in a console. Maybe it is caused by some preference in Komodo?
Another question is that I know in the interpreter, when I store some variables it will remember what I stored, like in a Matlab workspace. But in Komodo Edit, every time the program runs from the beginning and store no temporary variables for debugging. For example if I need to read in some large file and do some operations, every time I have to read it in again which takes a lot of time.
Is there a way to achieve instant output or temporary variable storage without typing every line into the interpreter directly, when using other environments like Komodo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python output is realtime.

If your output is not realtime, this is likely an artefact of Komodo Edit. Run your script outside of Komodo.

And Python, as any programming language, starts from scratch when you start it. How would it otherwise work?

If you want a interpreter-like situation you can use `import pdb;pdb.set_trace()` in your script. That will give you an interpreter prompt for debugging.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer!